# how to add arrays as azure devops variable groups variable value?

Tags: azure-devops

I have used azure devops variable group variables to define my appsettings properties. However, I could not use an array as a value for one of my appsettings properties.

Here is a screenshot of what i am trying to do:

[image]

But it appears on the appsettings.json as follows which results in a 500 internal server error `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: collection`

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
    "ClientId": "",
    "TenantId": "",
    "Audience": "[ https://api.doesnotexist.com ]"
}
```

The code in Startup.cs that is failing is as follows:

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.Authority = $"{azureADSettings.Instance}/{azureADSettings.TenantId}/";
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudiences = new List<string>(azureADSettings.Audience),
    };
});
```

Comment: Hi @blogs4t.Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set collection using the variables as explained [in the microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#json-variable-substitution-example)

By adding the index of the element in the variable name
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcDY8.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Please Refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch):

> All variables are stored as strings and are mutable. The value of a variable can change from run to run or job to job of your pipeline.

In Azure Devops, Variables are **String type** by default. And we couldn'change it.

So when you define an array in variable, it will pass the array as a string to your appsettings.json file.

To solve this issue, you need to change to [use Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#check-for-an-empty-parameter-object). The parameter supports the value of the input array type.

Here is an example:

```
parameters:
- name: 'param'
  type: object
  default: [123,234,456]


steps:
- ${{ each p in parameters.param }}:
  - script: echo ${{ p }}
```

**Note:** Parameters can only be used in YAML pipeline.

Comment: Hi. I am not declaring these variables in the pipeline. My question is about the variable groups where i do not know of a way to declare array of values for a appsetting property.

Comment: Hi @blogs4t. The varaibles in variable group are also the **String type**. You couldn't define the array in it. If you need to use array, you need to use the parameters in Yaml Pipeline